# Marking a column unique using WebMatrix

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, webmatrix

I have a table in WebMatrix which contains UserID and Username.

UserID is the Primary Key. Username is an nvarchar. How can I make it unique? At the moment, there can be multiple versions of the same username, which isn't good!

How can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a unique contstraint to the column in the database.

To add a unique constraint to the table the syntax for the sql is

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD CONSTRAINT
            <constraintname> UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
                <columnname>
    )
```

Comment: Yes, but how is this done in WebMatrix? I assume it's possible but I cannot figure out how to :)

Comment: you need to add an index to your database table. What kind of database are you using?

Comment: the database that is bundled with the WebMatrix IDE. SQL Server Compact.

Comment: I have now migrated to SQL Server.